# Google Maps : get route, Km, and ... price

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, variables

I think I am in a project which is probably too much for me, but I thought you could put me in the right direction.

We are trying to have a form where the user will write a starting point and an ending one, as seen in the Google Maps examples (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/directions-advanced.html), in order to output a map, the route in it, and the number of kilometers between the two points.

The thing is that we need to "translate" those Km into $.

I think this could be easily done, but we will have too some variables, like the number of passengers (a dropdown menu to select).

How on earth can I combine that ? Should I write a special form, use some PHP ? I'm lost here. How could I do it ?

Say that 1 km = 100$
and every extra person beyond the first one will add 100$ to that price.

So 20 Km with 2 persons = 300$

**1- Can I embedd some variable into the Google code ?**
**2- How would be the form to call for it ?**

Thanks very much for your help.

**Google Code**

> ```
> var map;
> var gdir;
> var geocoder = null;
> var addressMarker;
>
> function initialize() {
>   if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {      
>     map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
>     gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
>     GEvent.addListener(gdir, "load", onGDirectionsLoad);
>     GEvent.addListener(gdir, "error", handleErrors);
>
>     setDirections("San Francisco", "Mountain View", "en_US");
>   }
> }
>
> function setDirections(fromAddress, toAddress,
> ```
>
> locale) {
>         gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress,
>                   { "locale": locale });
>       }
>
> ```
> function handleErrors(){
>  if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS)
>    alert("No corresponding geographic location could be found for
> ```
>
> one of the specified addresses. This
>   may be due to the fact that the
>   address is relatively new, or it may
>   be incorrect.\nError code: " +
>   gdir.getStatus().code);
>        else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR)
>          alert("A geocoding or directions request could not be successfully
>   processed, yet the exact reason for
>   the failure is not known.\n Error
>   code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
>
> ```
>  else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_MISSING_QUERY)
>    alert("The HTTP q parameter was either missing or had no value. For
> ```
>
> geocoder requests, this means that an
>   empty address was specified as input.
>   For directions requests, this means
>   that no query was specified in the
>   input.\n Error code: " +
>   gdir.getStatus().code);
>
> //   else if (gdir.getStatus().code
>   == G_UNAVAILABLE_ADDRESS)  <--- Doc bug... this is either not defined, or
>   Doc is wrong  //     alert("The
>   geocode for the given address or the
>   route for the given directions query
>   cannot be returned due to legal or
>   contractual reasons.\n Error code: " +
>   gdir.getStatus().code);
>
> ```
>  else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_KEY)
>    alert("The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain
> ```
>
> for which it was given. \n Error code:
>   " + gdir.getStatus().code);
>
> ```
>  else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_REQUEST)
>    alert("A directions request could not be successfully parsed.\n
> ```
>
> Error code: " +
>   gdir.getStatus().code);
>
> ```
>  else alert("An unknown error occurred.");
>       }
> ```
>
> function onGDirectionsLoad(){ 
>         // Use this function to access information about the latest load()
>         // results.
>
> ```
>   // e.g.
>   // document.getElementById("getStatus").innerHTML
> ```
>
> = gdir.getStatus().code;    // and yada yada yada...  }

Answer (score 3):

Full code for you:

```
<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Distance Calculator</title> 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map_canvas { 
            height:500px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;  

    function initialize() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start");
        var end = document.getElementById("end");
        var autocompletePickpUp = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(start);
        var autocompleteDelivery = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(end);
        var uk = new google.maps.LatLng(51.511035, -0.132315);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom:12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: uk
        } 

        //testing


        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        autocompletePickpUp.bindTo('bounds', map); 
        autocompleteDelivery.bindTo('bounds', map);   

    }

    function calcRoute() { 
        var startValue =start.value;
        var endValue = end.value;
        var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distanceKm");
        var distanceMl = document.getElementById("distanceMl");
        var price = document.getElementById("price");

        var request = {
            origin:startValue, 
            destination:endValue,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000; 
                distanceMl.value =  response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value * 0.000621371;
                price.value = distanceMl.value * 2.50;

            }
        });         
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="start">Start: </label>
            <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />

            <label for="end">End: </label>
            <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />

            <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" /> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="distanceInKm">Distance (km): </label>
            <input type="text" name="distanceKm" id="distanceKm" readonly="true" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="distanceInMiles">Distance (ML): </label>
            <input type="text" name="distanceMl" id="distanceMl" readonly="true" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="price">Price: </label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" readonly="true" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

paste this in a html doc, and test it.
I'm getting the values in KM > convert it in Miles > and get a price in £.

I just did that now, and it is not 100% func but you get the idea.

To calc your passengers you just need to get this :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Table</label>
    <select class="form-control required" name="kitchen_table" id="kitchen_table">
       <option value="" selected>Quantity</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="10">1</option>
        <option value="20">2</option>
        <option value="30">3</option>
        <option value="40">4</option>
        </select>
     </div>

 <div class="live_quote">
         <p>Your total is: <span id="total_quote"></span> </p>
 </div>
```

and get the values to print it :

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var total = 0;

  $('select :selected').each(function() {
    total += Number($(this).val());
  });
$("#total_quote").html(total);
```

})

AGAIN: you may have some erro's, but it is func, you can get an idea and guide from there.

Answer (score 1):

In your onGDirectionsLoad() function, you can get the distance in km with

```
 gdir.getDistance().meters/1000
```

I assume you don't need me to tell you how to perform rounding, if necessary, multiply it by $100 and add the extra passenger fees.

Comment: Thanks Mike, what I don't get is the addition of the extra passengers, I wouldn't know how such function could be. If you give me the structural syntax I can figure it out :) Sorry I'm in my begginings

Comment: You don't say where your number of passengers information is held. If the user enters it into an input field you can use parseInt(document.getElementById("passengers").value).